# ByteArray to Vector = AS3 RangeError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, mp3, extract, fft

I'm trying to extract fft data from an mp3 without playing it.  I'm using AS3 and CS5.  I found a great real-time Spectrum Analyzer [here](http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/real-time-spectrum-analysis/), but it only works with the microphone.  I also found a great mp3 looper [here](http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2010/playback-mp3-loop-gapless/), which I'm using for sound extraction.  I'm essentially trying to combine the source found in both of those links.  I'm getting a RangeError while reading the byteArray data from the mp3 sample into the Vector used to make the fft.  The mp3 data is in stereo so I divide by 8 (4 bytes for the left channel, 4 for the right).  It reads through the loop just fine and traces the correct data but when it gets to the end I get the error, even if the loop is set to go through just one time.  Any and all help would be much appreciated.  Here is my code used to move the data into the Vector.

```
    public function readMp3(): void {

        for (var i:int = 0; i < byteArray.length/8; i++) {

            byteArray.position = i;

            /*
              m_buf is fed into the updateSpectrum function in 
              the Sound Analyzer
            */
            m_buf[i] = byteArray.readFloat();
            trace (m_buf[i]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: divide by 2 not 8. byteArray is right,left,right,left.... with 512 length if I remember correctly 256X256 Not sure about the figures its been about 3 years since I played with the sound functions.

Comment: Also try commenting out byteArray.position = i; when you readFloat I think it auto increments but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Actually forgot you have to divide depending on the sample rate used to make the byteArray.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  That was extremely helpful - the #2004 error is gone.  I am, however, now encountering a #2030  End of file was encountered.  Dividing by 4 is the best solution (that I can see).  It's making everything else run smoothly.  I'll look into how sample rate effects this though.  Thanks!!

Comment: Correcting my last comment.  Dividing by 8 is the best solution, because I needed to convert the stereo to mono by adding the left and right samples and then dividing by 2 to get the average.  If the mp3 was mono though then dividing by 4 would be best.